# Creating a PHP string to send with PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a contact form that sends a confirmation mail to the person that filled the form using PHPMailer. The mail is sent without line breaks, so I am trying to format the message sent, I have 2 problems.

1. There are no line breaks.
2. I have a `textarea` for inputting the message. Same problem, the message is sent without the line breaks.

Here is the code that sends the message

```
 $msg =  'Hello! ' . $from_name . 'Thank you...! For Contacting Us. ' . "\r\n" .    
         'Subject: ' . $email_subject . "\r\n" .
         'Message: ' . $email_message . "\r\n" .
         'This is a Contact Confirmation mail. We Will contact You as soon as possible' . "\r\n";
```

This is the variable that is sent through PHPMailer, the mail is not sent, there is an error (I don't know which, I just catch that the mail was not sent successfully). if I don't add the `"\r\n"` there are no problems.
The variable `$email_message` contains the `textarea` (also sent without line breaks).

Comment: What does the `phpmailer` documentation tell you?

Comment: the documentation doesn't show how to work with variables  $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';  I am just trying what will work, for now no luck (I am noob)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use phpmailer to send HTML messages and put each line in a `<p>` tag or just add `</br>`

Comment: Found the solution for problem number 1. The $mail->AltBody didn't allow the formatting. I will show my solution using <br /> after I found the solution to problem  2 with the text area that is being sent without line breaks still

Answer (score 1):

HTML does not preserve white space, which is why you're not seeing line breaks. You can tell PHPMailer not to use HTML like this:

```
$mail->isHTML(false);
$mail->Body = $msg;
```

When you send that your line breaks will be preserved.

Alternatively, keep it as HTML, but wrap your paragraphs in `<p>` tags or add line breaks with `<br>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used to my first problem is:

```
$msg =  'Hello! ' . $from_name . ' <br />' . 'Thank you...! For Contacting Us. <br />' .
                'Subject: ' . $email_subject . '<br />' .
                'Message: ' . $email_message . '<br />' .
                'This is a Contact Confirmation mail. We Will contact You as soon as possible' . '<br />';

         $msg_alt =  'Hello! ' . $from_name . 'Thank you...! For Contacting Us. ' .
                'Subject: ' . $email_subject . 
                'Message: ' . $email_message . 
                'This is a Contact Confirmation mail. We Will contact You as soon as possible';
```

I didn't realized that the problem was with AltBody message for not HTML messages.
Formatting there is not allowed (or i didn't find how to do it right).
For the text area problem I didn't find a solution yet.